# Why query is slow using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I made a ***PHP*** class for search database with some methods. i.e `LIKE`, `FULL TEXT` and `...`

I did test it on a huge database.   The search speed was great,  so I started to use this script in my page.

I decided to use **AJAX** to speed up stuff...

This is my ajax code :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: publisher + '&blur=true',
        url:"server/advance2.php",
        ifModified: true, /* tested with and without this */
        cache: true, /* tested with and without this */
        statusCode: { 404: function() {

                $('#target').html('<h4 class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3 textRed textCenter farsi">Error...</h4>');

            }//404
        },//statusCode
        beforeSend: function() {

            $('#target').html('<img src="e995a9c2864f.gif" class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3" alt="We are searching, please wait"/>');

        },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#target').html(result)
        }

    });//Ajax Request After Blur
```

but the search speed significantly decreased.

Would you tell me why it's happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Benchmark how long the query actually takes in the real code (simple logging statements with timestamp at start of SQL query and right after are sufficient).  The SQL query itself is not being made slower by Ajax.  It is something else not described in your question.

Comment: Go back to the way you had it?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck?  Debug your code to find out *specifically* what part is running slowly.  If the PHP code is taking a long time to respond to this AJAX call then there's no way for anybody to know why *the PHP code* is running slowly without seeing *the PHP code*.  If this code is running slowly, what part is the slow part?  When you step through in a debugger, which line of code takes the longest to execute?  To sum up... Don't ask us to *guess*.  Debug your code and *find out*.

Comment: @David: Aren't there profilers for PHP?  I have not done much with it since the late 90's, but I would hope there are.

Comment: @David if you look at my question again, I highlighted it... There's nothing wrong with php code

Comment: @EricJ. I tried `XDEBUG`...

Comment: Simply invoking SQL via Ajax will not make the SQL slower.  If there is a problem, it lies elsewhere.  It could be that your website is using different query parameters than you tested with that happen to be much slower.  It could be that (for some non-obvious reason) the Ajax callback is very slow.  There could be many factors, but Ajax magically making the SQL query slower is not one of them.

Comment: @mrm: And what happened when you tried XDEBUG?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of quick debugging ideas:

1) Open up the browser debugger, usually started with F12, make sure the the majority of the time of the response is waiting on the web server (vs rendering, etc.).

2) On the server side, find the db query log and see how long the query itself is actually taking.  As noted in other answers, there are a number of moving parts here.  You just need to step by step and find the one that's taking longer than expected.